# Question about pthreads & pointers

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Here is an example of thread creation code that is often seen. pthread_create uses a lot of pointers/addresses and I was wondering why this is so.

```
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    long t;
      for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
          rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, &someMethod, (void *)t);
      }
```

Is there a major advantage or difference for using the '&' to refer to the variable array 'threads' as well as 'someMethod' (as opposed to just 'threads' and just 'someMethod')? And also, why is 't' usually passed as a void pointer instead of just 't'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
    void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);
```

---

You need to pass a `pointer` to a `pthread_t` variable to `pthread_create`. `&threads[t]` and `threads+t` achieve this. `threads[t]` does not. `pthread_create` requires a pointer so it can return a value through it.

`someMethod` is a suitable expression for the third argument, since it's the address of the function. I think `&someMethod` is redundantly equivalent, but I'm not sure.

You are casting `t` to `void *` in order to jam a `long` into a `void *`. I don't think a `long` is guaranteed to fit in a `void *`. It's definitely a suboptimal solution even if the guarantee exists. You should be passing a pointer to `t` (`&t`, no cast required) for clarity and to ensure compatibility with the expected `void *`. Don't forget to adjust `someMethod` accordingly.

---

```
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
long t;
for (t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, someMethod, &t);
}
```